# Simple random sampling, average as a parameter

Tags: sampling

In a forest of 100 Acre, let 10 (1 acre size) plots be the sample.
Inside each plot, one took measurements of total trees and trees diameter.

It is reasonable to think about the number of trees inside each plot (counts).

However, in terms of tree diameter, it is reasonable to think about the average.
The sum of all tree diameters of each plot would not end up with some value that is useful, however, its average would describe better each plot.

The question itself is about if it is valid to calculate the sample error of a Simple Random Sampling like I have described but instead of using counts or sum (inside each plot) use the average of some variable (diameter in this case).

| PLOT | Number of Trees | Average Diameter (cm) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 103 | 34.3 |
| 2 | 120 | 31.2 |
| 3 | 98 | 34.7 |
| 4 | 145 | 29.7 |
| 5 | 99 | 41.5 |
| 6 | 107 | 38.4 |
| 7 | 78 | 34.1 |
| 8 | 139 | 37.4 |
| 9 | 115 | 29.7 |
| 10 | 103 | 27.2 |

Another thing that I have noticed is that:
If I take the SUM or the COUNT of some variable and summarize by plot, for example (Number of Trees) of the table, it will result the same as counting all the trees that I have measured (raw data).

However, the average by plot is not the same as the total average (raw data). In this case, which one is the best estimation of the mean? The raw data average of some variable or the average of the averages (by plot)?

Comment: So the forest is 100 acres, and you have 10 plots that are each 10 acres... Are these plots non-overlapping, thus forming a partition of the forest area? Or do they have overlap?

Comment: If they overlap, and you know by how much from GIS, consider using the [IE principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to produce a weighted sum that accounts for any overlap.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Why wouldn't it be?

Of all the things you can take the standard error of, the mean might be the most common.

BTW, the total diameter in each plot might also be interesting. Maybe more interesting than the average. It would be a good estimate of the total amount of tree in the plot.  This might be a more useful thing to know than the average, depending on your research question.

Comment: In [timber cruising](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/industry/forestry/competitive-forest-industry/timber-pricing/timber-cruising) the estimation of the total volume of wood (with some accountance of species and quality) goes into the value estimation. In British Columbia (Canada), this estimate of value is used for companies to bid on the right to harvest.

Comment: While it is rudimentary, a cone based on the diameter at breast height (sometimes defined as the diameter 1.3 meters above the point of germination) and the height makes for a useful first approximation for the volume of common conifer species in BC. The total diameter would be an interesting proxy for volume when the heights are difficult to measure, but in practice measuring the heights is routine.

Comment: The plots do not overlap.

All I have seen in many books is only example of statistics of counts and sums inside each sample plot.
They do sum volumes, basal area, they do count trees.
However, they do not take means of any variable.

Although all of their examples are excellent  to describe the forest, it is my need to know the mean diameter and also the mean tree height. I wish to calculate the sample error of these two variables in order to find out if my sample is enough to describe the population.